# Newline character in post request

Tags: post, newline, wget

I want to send new-line-character as part of a value of a post request (text)variable. I am using wget to fire the request. How do I code that ?

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Comment: Maybe same for curl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872427/how-to-send-line-break-with-curl

Answer (score 26):

According to [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1), you encode a line break as `%0D%0A` in the `x-www-form-urlencoded` format -- which is what you hand to the `--post-data` option to wget.

Comment: i didn't get it. what exactly to do. i selected x-www-form-urlencoded and added %0D%0A where ever line break needed. but it was passed as string. eg: content: something %0D%0A somewhere. the content param was passed as "something %0D%0A somewhere"

Comment: Note that the question (and the answer) were about sending request from shell scripts using the `wget` tool. I suspect your situation is different, please search for an answer that fits better.