# How can I rewrite this CURL multipart/form-data request without using -F?

Tags: http, curl, multipartform-data

How can I rewrite the following CURL command, so that it doesn't use the `-F` option, but still generates the exact same HTTP request?  i.e. so that it passes the multipart/form-data in the body directly.

```
curl -X POST -F example=test http://localhost:3000/test
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Solved:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------4ebf00fbcf09" \
  --data-binary @test.txt \
  http://localhost:3000/test
```

Where `test.txt` contains the following text, and most importantly has **CRLF (\r\n) line endings**:

```
------------------------------4ebf00fbcf09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example"

test
------------------------------4ebf00fbcf09--
```

Notes: it is important to use `--data-binary` instead of plain old `-d` as the former preserves the line endings (which are very important).  Also, note that the boundary in the body starts with an extra `--`.

I'm going to repeat it because it's so important, but that request-body file must have CRLF line endings. A multi-platform text editor with good line-ending support is jEdit ([how to set the line endings in jEdit](http://omegadelta.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/jedit_lineendings.png)).

If you're interested in how I worked this out (debugging with a Ruby on Rails app) and not just the final solution, I wrote up my debugging steps on [my blog](http://omegadelta.net/2012/05/26/debugging-multipartform-data-form-requests-with-ruby-on-rails/).

Comment: Well done, sir. It took me 4 hours straight to get to you telling me the line endings need to be CRLF. Thanks so much.

Comment: Tim, you're welcome. This puzzled me for ages. The RFC has the key http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046 (search 'CRLF'). The worse part is that curl will actually munge the line endings if you use `-d`!

Comment: Why for the love of Unix must the line endings be CRLFs?! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Also I just noticed, in your `test.txt` example you have a trailing `--`, is it on purpose?

Comment: @CamiloMartin yes, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1, specifically the text `The boundary delimiter line following the last body part is a distinguished delimiter that indicates that no further body parts
   will follow.  Such a delimiter line is identical to the previous
   delimiter lines, with the addition of two more hyphens after the
   boundary parameter value.` You only need to do this on the *last* item.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Thanks! You've cleared up many things nicely in this whole Q&A.

Comment: both links are broken

Comment: What would this look like if instead of plain text we wanted to POST an image?

Comment: What could be wrong, if this curl statement seems to send the wrong Content-length?

Answer (score 34):

You can use the `--form` argument with an explicitly

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/related" \
  --form "data=@example.jpg;type=image/jpeg" http://localhost:3000/test
```

Comment: thanks but I'm specifically wanting to pass in the raw data for testing, so that I can understand it – and then use it in a non-curl based program.

Comment: Thank you, the "type=..." helped me so much!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, given that it allows to do this with just curl CLI features and without constructing multipart requests by hand,

Answer (score 16):

Here's an alternative answer with the original CURL statement re-written using `-d` as a one-liner, without temporary files.  Personally I think the temporary files approach is easier to understand, but I'm putting this here for reference as well:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------4ebf00fbcf09" -d $'------------------------------4ebf00fbcf09\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="example"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n------------------------------4ebf00fbcf09--\r\n' http://localhost:3000/test
```

Notes: the `$'blar'` syntax is so that bash will parse the \r\n as a CRLF token. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295906/72176) for that tip.

Comment: Thanks. It's also helpful to note that the Content-Type header should not specify the boundary value unless you are also passing raw data with a static boundary value. Setting the boundary value while also using -F key=value parameters can make curl suffix a 2nd boundary= value, which is obviously unintended.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I'm using, I think it's clean and doesn't need temporary files nor gobbles up RAM in case you want to upload whole files (so no reading files into memory).

```
# Set these two.
file='path/to/yourfile.ext'
url='http://endpoint.example.com/foo/bar'

delim="-----MultipartDelimeter$$$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"
nl=$'\r\n'
mime="$(file -b --mime-type "$file")"

# This is the "body" of the request.
data() {
    # Also make sure to set the fields you need.
    printf %s "--$delim${nl}Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"${nl}Content-Type: $mime$nl$nl"
    cat "$file"
    printf %s "$nl--$delim--$nl"
}

# You can later grep this, or something.
response="$(data | curl -# "$url" -H "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$delim" --data-binary @-)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to upload one image file using "Content-Type: multipart/related",

```
curl --trace trace.txt -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=boundary_1234' --data-binary $'--boundary_1234\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n{\r\n\t"title": "TestFile"\r\n}\r\n\r\n--boundary_1234\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' --data-binary '@Image0177.jpg' --data-binary $'\r\n--boundary_1234--\r\n' 'http://localhost:3000/google/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how I would do it:

```
curl https://httpbin.org/post \
    -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----FormBoundary123456789' \
    --data-binary $'------FormBoundary123456789\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example"\r
\r
test\r
------FormBoundary123456789--\r
'
```

Or a bit more sophisticated (should be portable to most modern shells):

```
DELIM=----FormBoundary$RANDOM$RANDOM

curl https://httpbin.org/post \
    -H "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$DELIM" \
    --data-binary --$DELIM$'\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example"\r
\r
test\r
'--$DELIM--$'\r
'
```

Answer (score -3):

> This is for multipart/form-data request method. for uploading a file add --form filename="@path/image.jpg;type=image/jpeg"

curl --form key="value" --form key="value" http://localhost:3000/test

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since `-F` and `--form` are the same option; in the manual page `-F, --form <name=content>`.