# AWS API Gateway removing newlines from body

Tags: curl

My body mapping is defined as:

```
{
    "csv": "$input.body",
    "p1": false,
    "p2": "p3",
    "p3": "p4"
}
```

Invoking the function with

```
curl 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/xxx?p3=aaa&p4=bbb' \
-XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/csv"  -d @input.csv
```

Where input.csv contains

```
l1c1,l1c2
l2c1,l2c2
l3c1,l3c2
```

Will end up with calling my lambda function with

```
{
    "csv": "l1c1,l1c2l2c1,l2c2l3c1,l3c2",
    "p1": false,
    "p2": "p3",
    "p3": "p4"
}
```

Is there a way NOT to remove the newlines from the body? $input.body should evaluate to the "RAW PAYLOAD" according to the docs here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#d0e9653

Also tried using $util.escapeJavaScript($input.body), but it does not make any difference at all.

Decoding $util.base64Encode($input.body) also has the newlines stripped...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Turns out --data or -d sends the data as www-form-urlencoded, thus strips out new lines. --data-binary is the correct way to send the file in my case.

Answer (score 0):

From curl's [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar. When --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out.

See also: [How to send line break with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872427/how-to-send-line-break-with-curl)