# curl : post a field in a multipart form called file?

Tags: curl

I want to replace this:

```
curl -F 'file=@a.html' http://localhost:8080/convert
```

with

```
curl -F 'file=<html><body>Inline!</body></html>' http://localhost:8080/convert
```

but that just gets me: `curl: (26) couldn't open file "html><body>a</body></html>"`

using curl -d doesn't work (presumably because it doesn't generate a multipart body?)

How can I embed content in the curl parameter instead of relying on a reference to an actual file?

Comment: What I failed to notice both in the error message and the man page is that the leading '<' of <html> is parsed similarly to "@"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `--form-string` argument instead of -F, eg

`curl --form-string 'file=<html><body>Inline!</body></html>' http://localhost:8080/convert`

which yields

```
POST /convert HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 172
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------2e4ba7fc50e9eec8

--------------------------2e4ba7fc50e9eec8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

<html><body>Inline!</body></html>
--------------------------2e4ba7fc50e9eec8--
```

Comment: I think that your answer is much simpler and suitable as the answer for OP's issue. I could study from your answer. Thank you. And I'm really sorry for my ignorant answer. Although I cannot accept, I would like to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? I think that there might be several solutions. So please think of this as one of them. In order to send the content of `a.html` with multipart/form-data, the request body is required to be created and send it. As a example, this answer supposes as follows.

- `a.html` is `<html><body>Inline!</body></html>`.
- You use curl on bash.

The request body is as follows.

```
--boundaryboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body>Inline!</body></html>
--boundaryboundary--
```

Replace the line break to `\r\n` and send this.

```
--boundaryboundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.html"\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body>Inline!</body></html>\r\n--boundaryboundary--
```

#### Modified curl sample :

The modified curl sample is as follows. `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data; boundary=boundaryboundary`.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundaryboundary' \
  -d $'--boundaryboundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="a.html"\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body>Inline!</body></html>\r\n--boundaryboundary--' \
  'http://localhost:8080/convert'
```

#### Reference :

- [About `$'--boundaryboundary...'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872427/how-to-send-line-break-with-curl/5295906#5295906)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Excellent. Yes this works, and seems fairly straightforward to work with. I was hoping to not have to manually construct the form data but in fact it's simple enough so long as you know the rules for line breaks and boundaries

Comment: @Chris F Carroll Thank you for replying. And I have to apologize to you. Now I noticed another answer. I think that hanshenrik's answer is much simpler and suitable as the answer for your issue. So please accept hanshenrik's answer. And I'm really sorry for my ignorant answer.

Comment: I agree that form-string is the the simpler thing, but since your answer both works and demonstrates other things too, it is still a valuable answer.

Comment: @Chris F Carroll Thank you for your response and your concern.