# cURL config file (-k / --config) JSON newlines

Tags: curl, character-encoding, heredoc

I'm trying to construct a cURL config file that contains newlines in the `-d`/`--data` body but it doesn't seem to work the same as on the command line.

On the command line I can run:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/mytype/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

And the data body is correctly passed along.

However, if I try to do this in a curl `-K`/`--config` file, it doesn't work.

test.curl:

```
-XPUT
-d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

and then run `curl -K test.curl 'http://localhost:9200/mytype/_search` and the endpoint I submit data to fails to parse.  I can make it work if I put all of the data on a single line and use double quotes, but that kills some of the legibility I'm looking for.

test2.curl works

```
-XPUT
-d "{\"query\": {\"match_all\": {} } }"
```

I have also attempted to replicate this `heredoc` answer: [How to send line break with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872427/how-to-send-line-break-with-curl) but again it does not work in a `--config` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `-d "{\"query\": {\"match_all\": {} } }"` You can do `data-binary = "@requestbody.json"`

Then in requestbody.json:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```