# \n escaped when writing to a file in Go

Tags: bash, go, curl, line-breaks

I have created a webserver that receives POST requests, creates a txt file and prints it using the lp command.

However, those strings coming from a request that contains "\n" are saved into the file with \n as a text instead of creating a line break.

If I declare a hard-coding string, the line breaks are created.

This is the relevant code:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    bodyBuffer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/print.txt", bodyBuffer, 0644)
    //... More code
}
```

If I run this command:

```
curl -X POST --data "My\nName" http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

The text file generated contains: My\nName instead of two lines.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. It's how you invoke your handler, via `curl`, and how you pass arguments to `curl`. Possible duplicate of [How to send line break with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872427/how-to-send-line-break-with-curl)

Comment: You are right. I have used curl -X POST --data $'My\nName' http://127.0.0.1:8080/  instead and the line-breaks are created. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

"My\nName" does not interpolate `\n` to a newline

```
echo "My\nName"
My\nName
```

However there are ways of doing this in the shell

```
echo "$(printf 'My\nName')"
My
Name
```

Your Go is fine, the curl bash side is not behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use `curl -X POST --data $'My\nName' http://127.0.0.1:8080/` instead. $-strings (in Bash) is ANSI-C quoting which supports all C-like escape sequences including "\n".