# nodeJS file upload server does not change line

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I have a very simple file uploader script in which I want to append some logs to a nodejs server of mine. It successfully gets the data of the file but it fails to change line at server-side.

This is my script so far:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        if(req.method== 'POST'){
                console.log('bhke sto POST');
                if (req.url == '/logs/upload/Accelerometer.csv') {
                        console.log("Calledeixa to swsto path");

                        var body="";
                        req.on('data', data=>{

                        body+=data;
                        console.log("partial data ="+data);

                        fs.appendFile('Accelerometer.csv', body, function (err) {
                                console.log('Saved!');
                        });


                        });

                        console.log(body);

                        req.on('end', function(){
                        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'})
                        res.end('Accelerometer.csv was updated successfully\n');
                        });

                } else {
                        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
                        res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
                        res.write('<input type="submit">');
                        res.write('</form>');
                        return res.end();
                }
        }
}).listen(8080);
```

I debug it using curl and a random file. The command I use is `curl -X POST -d @filename 127.0.0.1:8080/logs/upload/Accelerometer.csv`

And the contente of the file are:

0,0,0

1,2,3

2,4,7

But at server-side I get this:

[image]

How can I make the server-side file have the same format as the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because `curl` removes `linebreaks` from data posted with the `-d` option. Use `--data-binary` options instead.

Here's more [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872427/how-to-send-line-break-with-curl) about sending `newline` with curl.